# is it possible to store m - m / Y formatted datetime with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sqldatatypes

I need to store month - month / year formatted data in an SQL Server database. 01 - 12 / 2014 means, for instance, January 2014 to December 2014. Should I use varchar datatype or is it possible to do this with datetime datatype?

Comment: Use two columns and store the start and end date. Ignore the day part and you'll be golden.

Comment: it is actually possible, if you abuse the day part of the date column to store the other month. Disclamer, I would never use this method, searching it, reading it, commenting it would be awful. If you use this method do not include my name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this with a single `date` column in SQL Server.  I would encourage you to store this as two `date` columns, such as:  `BeginDate` and `EndDate`.  That would be the best way to a period of time using native SQL types.

If you *have* to store this as a `varchar()`, then put the field in sensible order.  Use a format like:    'YYYYMM-YYYYMM'.  This allows each component to be parsed out easily and to be sorted by the first value.  However, let me repeat my first advice:  the best way to store a range of time is to use two columns, one for the start date and one for the end date.